# Energy harvesting - drain capacitor when voltage is reached, ultra low power

Tags: cmos, energy-harvesting, fet

I want to connect tiny solar cell to a capacitor, let it charge it and once voltage reaches 2V - flush it through tiny red LED.

Could anyone suggest how to implement that given that charge current is very small (1 uA - 10 nA) and this periodic discharging should obviously have some hysteresis? I suppose I need some CMOS/FET active elements, but beyond that I have no idea.

Ideally it should make these flashes more frequent when more light is present.

Comment: Possibly the simplest version of this is simply to use a "flashing LED", which have a tiny controller on the die and will not turn on until the voltage exceeds its threshold. Datasheets don't detail leakage current so experimentation required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want a SRC, except that the off-state leakage needs to be very low.  Triggering it will also be tricky without using some current before the threshold is reached.

A real SCR will probably have too much leakage, but you can make the equivalent of a SCR for low currents with a couple of bipolar transistors:

[image]

The question now is how to trigger this.  A resistive voltage divider from the supply would probably rob too much current.

Here is a flaky idea I just came up with but haven't tried.  Use a few diodes of the same type from the same batch as a voltage divider.  The idea being that the current thru the chain would be virtually 0 when the voltage is low, and quickly go up as the threshold is reached.  Here is the concept:

[image]

Again, I haven't tried this.  D2 thru D8 basically form a voltage divider that creates 1/7 of the voltage at the top of D8.  The current will be essentially 0 until there is a few 100 mV accross each diode.  As the voltage builds, the current will build quickly as a function of the voltage.  R1 causes a little more voltage on the base of Q1 than is accross D8 when the current thru the diode chain builds.  At that point the current that would have gone thru D8 will go into the base of Q1.  Even when tiny, that current will get amplified by Q1, which is then amplified by Q2, which is then fed back to Q1, etc, to irrevesibly turn on the SCR.

I don't know what kind of current it will take to turn on the SCR, but all you need is to have the transistors get above unity gain.  I'm guessing a µA or so is probably good enough, but you would have to try this.  Datasheets don't tell you much about what transistors do at such small currents.

Here is another idea.

[image]

The SCR made from two small signal transistors still does the work, but this time it is triggered with a FET that has the appropriate gate threshold voltage.  That's going to be more flaky and unpredictable since FETs don't magically come on at some "threshold", and even if so, that will vary from part to part.

R1 is there to keep the SCR off until the FET is really starting to conduct, not just allowing normal leakage thru.  I haven't tried this either, but for a one-off it might work by selecting the appropriate FET manually.

The base drop of Q2 will probably be only in the 500 mV range when it reaches unity current gain and the SCR triggers.  With the example 2 MΩ resistor there, that only means a loss of 1/4 µA.  Of course you'd adjust R2 to be as high as possible but still not trigger the SCR from the FET leakage current.

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat way of doing this with a couple of BJTs, the effect uses Negative Differential Resistance and there is an old paper from the 1980s kicking about that covers it nicely - it was used in an energy harvesting application at the IEEE Sensors 2009 conference. I cited it in my phd thesis, when I can get to I'll dig out the citations.

I've also done this using an XLP Pic in sleep mode, if you shut everything down in the pic the sleep current is lower than the output of the solar cell, use the watchdog timer to wake the pic up every few seconds, sample the internal reference voltage and from that you can calculate Vdd (as a multiple of Vref) and decide when if you want to fully wake up or go back to sleep. I explain this  more fully in this paper:

http://digital-library.theiet.org/content/journals/10.1049/iet-wss.2010.0053

Let me know if you can't get access and I can send you the relevant segment when I next have access to it.

Comment: Are you referring to the [Esaki oscillator](http://cappels.org/dproj/simplest_LED_flasher/Simplest_LED_Flasher_Circuit.html) circuit? Disadvantage of this particular oscillator is its high operating voltage. A regular transistor breaks down only at 6V or so.

Comment: No, not that one, I'll dig it out when I can

Comment: @jippie Esaki oscillator looks really cool, although voltage is very sad. I guess even most "sensetive" RF BJT's won't work in this mode at 2V... :-|

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at BEAM robotics and their solar engines. It is a field that is doing almost exactly what you describe. Only they use motors instead of just LED.

Take a look at the Solar engines here: http://www.beam-wiki.org/wiki/Solar_Engine

You might be especially interested in Voltage triggered Type 1 engines.

The most basic circuit is based on 1381 voltage supervisor chip that triggers once the voltage reaches certain value. It then opens a transistor that drains the capacitor.

The 1381 part is hard to get in Europe but you can use TC54 from Microchip (http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010716) instead if you are located there. Both parts are manufactured with different trigger voltages and consume very little energy.

If you are interested in discrete solution, there are other circuits that can be used on that site. One example might be the diode triggered engine.